# Receive push notification when a user I'm following tweets specific hashtag

Tags: twitter, push-notifications

Is there a way to configure the Twitter app for Android to submit a push notification when a tweet by a user I'm following contains a specific hashing I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Twitter app, but if you're willing to use this site: https://ifttt.com/

then yes, it's possible.

At this point IFTTT does not appear to let you push tweets by a user other than yourself, so will not accomplish what is being asked.